# What is the meaning of "every once in a while"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have read this sentence, but cannot understand the meaning of *every once in a while*:

> My dad, he's on Facebook every once in a while.

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means [sometimes, every so often](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/once+in+a+while), without regularity:

> My dad, he's on Facebook *sometimes*.

Answer (score 3):

The "*while*" here indicates a period of time and "*once in a while*" implies something that happens infrequently during said period. The "*every*" is optional.

The phrase is similar in *structure* to "*every five minutes*" and in *meaning* to another common phrase, "*every now and then*".